simple phase modulation on wired serial line
Assume we have a serial communication system over a wire. Instead of sending pulses for bits, bits can be encoded in phase of a baseband sinusoid, like baseband QPSK(not modulated over a high frequency, each symbol is a sinusoid and phase changes between bits), Why this is not used in practice?
This is more prone to noise and bitrate is higher.

A timing diagram of your intended modulation would be a useful addition to your question. You can rest assured that any conceivable method of sending serial data has been tried somewhere, at some time. A better question would be when and where was this method used.

who says it's not used in practice?

baseband BPSK sounds like Manchester encoding, with square wave instead of sinewave.

I recall hearing of some signaling standards perhaps used in power distribution that are AC coupled and mostly CW, but don't recall any names. Perhaps this comment jogs someones' memory?

Obviously, we're not talking about "slow" local serial buses (thinking of, say, a 112 kbd UART connection between a microcontroller and a thermal printer, or a 12 Mb/s USB connection), because, well, there's no need to be smarter (read: more expensive) than "hey, high means 1, low means 0, and here's a bit of framing" if even the worst connection suffices for that.
BPSK like that exists in the form NRZ; in that case, the sine wave is at f=0 Hz, but it's just a special case.
The modulation with a non-zero-frequency sine only brings complexity and no real benefits, far as I can tell:

NRZ can be received with discrete-amplitude components only, trivially
NRZ only has a DC component problem if you send long runs of identical data,

which you don't do, anyways, that's why every system that avoids DC in a local bus typically has line coding that incorporates a balancing scheme, see, for example 8b/10b


You increase the bandwidth by at least a factor of 2: you really want to choose a sine wave whose frequency is higher than the symbol rate (I challenge you to build a good detector for 1/4 circle phase jumps every < 1/2 oscillation; you need to sample that at which rate? Draw the spectrum of your proposed system with an f_carrier < baud rate and sinc pulse shape in frequency / rectangular pulse shape in time domain to see the problem.)

this might still be desirable in incredibly specific cases where your channel has e.g. randomly appearing spectral notches in a < baud rate regime. But I'd really have to sit down, and do a lot of brain storming to come up with a problem that would result in this. And even then, it's really not obvious to me that PSK would be even remotely the solution of choice there - to me it would sound like technically, you'd just up the baud rate and add line and channel coding, in practical scenarios.




This is more prone to noise and bitrate is higher.

Only as you choose the carrier high enough to allow for orthogonal I and Q, you get twice the channel usage per unit bandwidth, but that's explicitly not what you wanted to do.
The technical reason this is commonly not done is that your receiver needs to be coherent. You can demodulate most baseband buses simply after recovering the symbol clock – no need to also recover the carrier frequency and carrier frequency phase. So, technically, PAM-4 can be easier to implement than QPSK, and gets the same bit/s/Hz. PAM good enough for Fast, Gigabit Ethernet over copper (PAM-5), 2.5, 5 and 10 Gigabit Ethernet over copper wire (PAM-16), and these are already all long-haul links, where the cost-per-lane can be a bit higher than for most serial buses. In PCI Express, gegenerations 1.0 through 5.0 use NRZ, and 6.0 uses PAM-4 – admittedly, with a lot of equalization, but still, this is incoherent reception, allowing a receiver to work relatively quickly.
This is not really a definition or anything, but the moment you have to modulate onto a carrier wave, your device usually stops being called a "serial transceiver" unit or such, and becomes a Modem ("modulator-demodulator", if you wonder where that term comes from). And there's plenty of wired communications over a single wire (so, technically, "serial", but nobody would call them that) that incorporate phase to transport information. The1980 Bell 201A telephone modem at 600 Bd => 1200 b/s uses QPSK, but was to my knowledge the only telephone modem generation that did that – the channel just doesn't fit that very well; you have an SNR that is better than you need for QPSK on a telephone line, if you care enough to equalize, channel code and map with the same effort as needed for high-rate QPSK transmission. Most post-1980 telephone modems go for 16-QAM or higher modulations.

The reason to not use PAM is the channel I'm intending to use this on is not actually a wire, it has noise and interference where encoding information in phase is more tolerant to noise. Also I thought using a sine that changes phase in between should have lower BW compared to a series of sharp pulses.

No, phase is not more tolerant to noise, that's simply a wrong claim. You'll find that in an maximum likelihood detector, which is the best you could do, the Euclidean distance matters, and only that. So whether you achieve that Euclidean distance via phase variations or amplitude variations straight up doesn't matter at all. You need to look at the actual technical case – as I explained in length in my answer.

And your bandwidth consideration is completely wrong, and it would give you a zero points on a digital communications engineering exam question: The bandwidth of a linear modulation exclusively depends on the pulse shape at a given symbol rate; not of the kind of modulation.

I said pulse shape not modulation. Not sure where did you draw that from.

"changes phase in between should have a lower BW then series of sharp pulses": Exactly here. You act as if the alternative is sharp pulses; it's not. The bandwidth depends on how these pulses are shaped, and whether you use that shape to form phase shift keying symbols or amplitude symbols makes no difference to bandwidth. Pulse shaping is used in either case!

More or less because it doesn't matter.  That said, there are examples of non-baseband (DC-balanced or AC coupled) codes, which are used in various applications.  Typically these are where galvanic isolation is desirable (Ethernet for example), or where DC isn't transmitted at all by the medium (like magnetic storage media, or radio as such).
I suppose the signals to/from a hard disk head might be a questionable example, as they're not really modulated for sake of the short transmission line between head and head amplifier, heh.  But these have used Manchester coding (FM, MFM) for example, with modern examples using more advanced codes.  (10BASE-T Ethernet is also Manchester encoded.)
The ratio of bandwidth to center frequency generally depends on the medium.  Wire transmission line generally has excellent bandwidth, including down to DC, so it's fine to use broad/base-band signals, like UART, with it.  Likewise, AC-coupled signals like Ethernet use quite wide bandwidth (roughly 100kHz to 100MHz), just cutting out the bottom [DC to 100kHz] to allow transformer coupling so you don't have to worry about hazardous voltages on the cable between sites (ground loop, lightning induced surge, etc.).
For lower quality and longer distance lines (particularly those that might be  spliced, run through various environments, subject to corrosion, etc., like phone lines), typically a multi-band approach is used.  Frequency-division multiplex (FDM) divides the medium's total bandwidth into channels, which may only be usable up to some bitrate each, but by collecting many together into a single link, total bandwidth can be optimized.  This includes modern longish-distance high-speed links like DSL and DOCSIS, and older back-haul links like phone trunking lines (where the channels are individual 3kHz phone lines).
For serial/UART traffic, isolation generally isn't required, and at typical low bitrates, cheap optical isolator devices are sufficient (like with MIDI).
Which, optical isolation can be considered an application of modulation itself: the light, though incoherent, is still amplitude-modulated by the signal, and an incoherent detector (photodiode/transistor) suffices to demodulate it.
Bandwidth is one of the limitations of UART style signals, though, and along with typical signaling standards like RS-485, distance is typically limited to a few km.  With repeaters or hubs, line loss can be mitigated, but one may well desire a more effective coding scheme over such distances.
